# Hyper-V Server R2 - Disk management MMC returns RPC Server is unavailable

Tags: hyper-v, windows, diskmanagement

does someone faced error "The RPC server is unavailable" during connecting to Disk management MMC console to Hyper-V Server R2? Servers are in the same AD domain and MMC console is enabled on Hyper-V.

Thanks

Comment: Both source and destination are 2008 R2?

Comment: Yes. Both R2. I can access firewall settings, server management snapin but Disk Management returns mentioned error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to change the Firewall rules on both machines (NOT only the Hyper-V Server)

Run this command on both machines:

**netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Volume Management" new enable=yes**

Comment: GREAT. Updating firewall on both sides was the case. Thank you

Comment: I'm still getting this. It was succesfull on my physical machine, but when I executed this command on my Virtual Client, it said: "No rules matched the given criteria". That's translated, since the machine runs Dutch language.

Comment: @KdgDev you will need to find the Dutch version of that text "Remote Volume Management"

Answer (score 1):

For errors "RPC Server is unavailable" when trying to use Disk Management MMC or Server Manager MMC or Computer Management MMC to connect to a Windows Hyper-V (Hyper V) Core Server, please note the following:
1. Enabling "Remote Volume Management" needs to be done on both machines... the Core Hyper V Server and the client machine: 
On the client machine (Windows 7 and Windows 8 ... XP is no longer supported... lol ;), "netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Volume Management" new enable=yes" will run smoothly.

On the Windows Hyper-V  (hyper V) Core Server (in my case I am on Server 2012 R2), I was not eble to run the netsh command. I was able to enable "Remote Volume Management" by using the GUI tool "Corefig for Windows Server 2012 Core and Hyper-V Server 2012"... *downloadable from http://corefig.codeplex.com/releases. Version 1.1.1 was stable enough.
Good luck!

Comment: This fixed my problem. Even though the firewall rule on the **server** was enabled, I needed to enable it on the computer where the management console was running also.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Windows is using dynamic port allocation for some services e.g. Disk management. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929851?wa=wsignin1.0 Meaning Microsoft finally uses one of these ports 49152 - 65535.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to change the Firewall rules on both machines (NOT only the
>   Hyper-V Server)
>
> Run this command on both machines:
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Volume Management"
>   new enable=yes

In Brazilian Portuguese, the group name is "Gerenciamento de Volumes Remoto".